# How to pull most recent gas price from this example page

Tags: php, html, dom, curl

I am trying to pull the most recent gas price at a set interval (say everyday) from [this website](http://www.atlantagasprices.com/index.aspx?area=Decatur&area=North%20Decatur) using php. I want to then apply my own formatting to it.

How can I go about this?

I tried to read up on simple HTML DOM but I am kind of new to programming and so, I'm a little confused.
If anyone can guide me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I just checked the link, the prices are pretty cleverly hidden in the css.

Comment: "Cleverly" is overstating a bit.  Extracting the info would mean simply taking all the `.sp_p [class^=p]`s and noting the second character of the class name (which will match `[0-9.]`).

Comment: @AuntJamaima no offense, but it is idiotic way of hiding data. Because it really does not help or hide. Anyone who can hack together few php functions can extract that data easily.

Comment: Before either of you even commented I extracted the prices list in the answer below. I don't know what purpose they had in obscuring the prices the way they did, beside maybe making someone take an extra 10 minutes to lift the data.

Answer (score 1):

The following should give you an idea to get you through the hardest part. It rips all the prices from the cleverly masked css. You would need to use two other regular expressions to get the gas station names and address.

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents("http://www.atlantagasprices.com/index.aspx?area=Decatur&area=North%20Decatur");
preg_match_all('/<div class=\"p\d/',$page,$pricesRaw);

foreach($pricesRaw[0] as $key => $value)
{
    $priceDigits[$key] = str_replace('<div class="p','',$value);
}

$x=0;
$prices = array();
while($x<count($priceDigits))
{
    array_push($prices, $priceDigits[$x].".".$priceDigits[$x+1].$priceDigits[$x+2]);
    $x=$x+3;
}

var_dump($prices); //this only shows that the prices array now holds all the gas prices listed on the page.

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking us to write code for you?

If not you do like this:

1. use php curl to grab page
2. use http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php to grab content
3. run your php as daily cron

Comment: Thanks so much for all the responses ! I didn't want the entire code written...I just wanted to be pointed in the right direction of the tools that I should be using to achieve the solution to my problem.